# Create total energy savings ticker based on time passed

Tags: javascript, counter, ticker

Basically I would like to create a running ticker that continually (every 1-15 seconds, it doesn't matter) that would update that total amount energy savings that our company saved based on a set equation (such as 25 cents per minute).  It would be based on the actual clock/calendar time, not just time that the visitor has accessed the page.

I'm looking to use javascript to do this (or jQuery) but I'm new to both languages with little experience.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Doing your calculations and updating them on a regular interval isn't very hard. You'll need to use the [JavaScript Date Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) to get your time. You can also use a setInterval function to perform your regular updates.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your level of knowledge about javascript but there are two function called window.setInterval and window.clearInterval that you can use to generate events at specific intervals.

Answer (score 0):

you could use window.setInterval(function,time in milliseconds);
basically:

```
var money_value=0.25;  //25 cents
var timing=15;     //15 seconds
var global_calculator=0;   //start time  could be brought in by php or whatever
window.setInterval("calculate()",timing*1000);  //timing*1000 milliseconds
                                                // means 15 seconds

function calculate(){
   global_calculator+=15; //add the passed seconds to the total of seconds
   total=global_calculator*money_value;  //calculate the total savings
   update_clock();   //your function that updates the values some where to show them;
}
```

that should be it.